# error: nested class in a nested class in a template class "is not a type"

Tags: c++, class, templates, g++, mingw

I bring here 3 versions of code, the first one causes a compilation error, the second and the third were compiled successfully.

---

## Code 1:

I created class `Bottom` is a nested class in `Middle` which is a nested class in a template class `Top`

```
template <class>
struct Top {
    struct Middle {
        struct Bottom {};
    };
    void useclass(Middle::Bottom);
};
```

This code gives an error:

```
main.cpp:6:27: error: 'Top::Middle::Bottom' is not a type
 void useclass(Middle::Bottom);
                       ^
```

## Code 2:

Similar to Code 1 but with `Top` is a normal class (non-template)

```
struct Top {
    struct Middle {
        struct Bottom {};
    };
    void useclass(Middle::Bottom);
};
```

This code was compiled successfully without any errors

## Code 3:

Similar to Code 1 but with method `useclass` taking `Middle` instead of `Bottom`

```
template <class>
struct Top {
    struct Middle {
        struct Bottom {};
    };
    void useclass(Middle);
};
```

This code was compiled successfully as well

---

Please tell me:

- Why Code 1 can't be compiled, which rule of C++ prevents it from being compiled?
- Is there any way to use *a nested class in a nested class in a template class* like `Bottom` as a type?

Comment: @PeteBecker I updated, thank you!

Comment: @M.M Not even that.  It is a dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/610245/where-and-why-do-i-have-to-put-the-template-and-typename-keywords

Comment: @NathanOliver which part of that code explains OP's situation exactly? It's not clear to me

Comment: @M.M Doesn't *The "typename" keyword
The answer is: We decide how the compiler should parse this. If t::x is a dependent name, then we need to prefix it by typename to tell the compiler to parse it in a certain way.* and the preceding information make that clear?

Comment: No. Why is Middle::Bottom dependent and not Middle? They're both in Top. How can `useclass(Middle::Bottom)` be parsed wrong?

Comment: @M.M I did figured it out, and I updated it, but the update doesn't answers the question completely: I hadn't pointed out *which rule of C++*. So, I didn't placed it in the answer box.

Comment: @DMaster it's still an answer even if it's lacking in explanation compared to other possible answers (which haven't been posted)

Comment: @M.M Because you can explicitly specialize `Middle` later?

Comment: @T.C. I tried that but it gives an error that explicit specialization may not follow instantiation (`void useclass(typename Middle::Bottom)` apparently causes instantiation)

Comment: @M.M Right, because instantiates the class instantiates the declaration which instantiates `Middle`, but if you have something using `Middle::Bottom` in the body rather the signature then the explicit specialization will go through.

Answer (score 2):

I just firgured it out, I need to place `typename` before `Middle::Bottom` in Code 1 and it would be compiled successfully.

```
template <class>
struct Top {
    struct Middle {
        struct Bottom {};
    };
    void useclass(typename Middle::Bottom);
};
```

**P.S.** I still expect some answers with more details, e.g. Why compiler doesn't recognize `Middle::Bottom` as a type without a keyword `typename`?